# Passing large artifacts between Gitlab-CI jobs without uploading to gitlab

Tags: gitlab, continuous-integration

I have a Gitlab-CI pipeline that builds the project in one job and want to keep the output binaries for a separate job. However the output binary folder is ~8GB and cannot be uploaded to gitlab (limit of 1GB upload) and hence the job fails. The reason I want the binaries to be passed to different jobs is that I want one of the jobs that uses it to be run manually after other jobs have run.

Is it possible to pass large artifacts between jobs without uploading it to gitlab.com?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of Passing the output binary folder via GitLab artifacts, maybe you can push it to some artifactory store such jfrog Repository .
And in the next stage, you can pull the binaries from the jfrog artifactory and work on that binary.

Comment: Thanks, that could work. For now I just went with using gitlab caches instead of artifacts. It allows for locally storing a cache of the required files.

Comment: yes, you can store the files using cache as well but it will be coupled with the gitlab host instance itself. So may be it is better to use a artifactory store